# Oracle SQL Row Number selection

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

These below all relate to the same record in the same file....basically it is labelled 'UNK' until someone assigns a product number to it.  in this case the number 12345678 was assigned by Paul on 01Jan.  Each record before/after that is when someone changes something on that record.

What I want is to capture that record, the 1st time when it goes from UNK to a number... and capture the user name and date etc from that line.

I have tried min, least, and I'm not sure about rownum or where to put the string if I did.

```
Car_Id    Product #     user name     date
111          unk           john          20Dec
111          unk           alan          25Dec
111          unk           pete          30Dec
111          12345678      paul          01Jan
111          12345678      jim           10Jan
222          unk           alan          25Dec
222          unk           pete          30Dec
222          87654321      paul          02Jan
222          87654321      steve         05Jan
```

But in logical terms I want it to do this... give me the 1st record after UNK.

Please can I have the full string if possible.

Comment: First according to what? (product#, username, date, or combination? Can you have several items with same username and/or date?

Comment: Which database are you using?  PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...

Comment: Oracle SQL.. i want the 1st record according to the Product #.. so say there are 5 people in a group, all doing the same job.... but i want to know who assigned this particular product # to this record... in this case it was Paul that assigned it on 01Jan. so i can run stats on who's done what.   also you can have the same person doing all 6 entries, but they'd all have a different date/timestamp on them.

Comment: Is there something else that links the rows? Presumably you have many different product #'s in your table; what differentiates one unk row for an as-yet-unassigned product # A with one that's going to be assigned to product # B?

Comment: The primary key is called...car_id.... so the file itself will have thousands of diffferent products, and the above will all be the same car_id for all UNK/12345678 records.   i.e the above records will all be Car_id 111..... the next product in the file...Unk/Unk/1234555 will all have a different car_id... say 222.  etc.    I select Car_Id when i am matching with other files.   my problem with the below string was where i put the 'where rownum = 1', because it was only bring forward 1 record from the whole file, instead of the 1st number record from each car_id. sorry i hope that makes sense.

Comment: i have edited the original question to show car_id... hope this helps thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like maybe the analytic function row_number() would be the best way to do this:

```
with sample_data as (select 111 car_id, 'unk' product#, 'john' user_name, to_date('20/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 111 car_id, 'unk' product#, 'alan' user_name, to_date('21/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 111 car_id, 'unk' product#, 'pete' user_name, to_date('22/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 111 car_id, '12345678' product#, 'paul' user_name, to_date('23/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 111 car_id, '12345678' product#, 'jim' user_name, to_date('24/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 222 car_id, 'unk' product#, 'alan' user_name, to_date('25/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 222 car_id, 'unk' product#, 'pete' user_name, to_date('26/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 222 car_id, '87654321' product#, 'paul' user_name, to_date('27/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual union all
                     select 222 car_id, '87654321' product#, 'steve' user_name, to_date('28/12/2014 10:12:24', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from dual)
select car_id,
       product#,
       user_name,
       dt
from   (select sd.*,
               row_number() over (partition by car_id order by dt) rn
        from   sample_data sd
        where  product# != 'unk')
where  rn = 1;

    CAR_ID PRODUCT# USER_NAME DT                   
---------- -------- --------- ---------------------
       111 12345678 paul      23/12/2014 10:12:24  
       222 87654321 paul      27/12/2014 10:12:24
```

Comment: thanks... i dont want the UNK records though... from the top list i want to find.. 111   12345678 paul 01Jan.....and 222  87654321 paul 02Jan... as they are both the 1st numbered records straight after UNK.  If i say WHERE product <> 'UNK'  and ROWNUM = 1 it doesnt find anything because the 1st rownum is UNK.

Comment: If you haven't worked with analytic functions before, I highly recommend you do so; they're incredibly flexible and very useful! *{:-)

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but your data seems to be ordered by date, so logically you could just take the first recoredset where the productnumber is not "unk".

```
Select *
From (SELECT * FROM YourTable orderby date) t -- make sure data is ordered before selecting it
where t.ProductNr <> 'unk' and -- don't get data without a number
rownum = 1 -- take the first
```

Comment: this sounds like the right way... because i am joining with other files i cant seem to get the it round the right way...........           select blah blah...            from SBH_CAR car
  left outer join 
  (
  select car_id, product, modified_date, modified_by 
  from sbh_car_aud order by modified_date) car1
  on car1.car_id = car.car_id
  WHERE CAR1.product <> 'UNK' and rownum = 1           have i got something round the wrong way?     its saying sql not properly ended, do i need a bracket somewhere?